# Pre-populating PowerPoint file with Excel input

Tags: excel, vba, templates, ms-office, powerpoint

I am currently in the following situation:

- I have an Excel file where I perform calculations and charts + diagrams are created based on the calculations.
- I have a PowerPoint report where I have to copy-paste these visualizations into.

I will need to repeat this process for many Excel files, all containing the same lay out. You can view them as a questionnaire: each Excel file is completed with different answers, though the structure remains the same.

Is there a way for me to create a template PowerPoint report file, where at the start I select which Excel file to 'load', and it pre-populates my PowerPoint file with the correct charts from the selected Excel file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ndeed, there is a free option available. With [SlideFab 2](https://slidefab.com) (lite) you can automate Excel to Powerpoint without coding: You would need to setup the Powerpoint template and link all shapes with the required Excel ranges or charts. Then SlideFab creates the slides for you. When the structure is really the same, you could just let SlideFab connect to the next Excel file and rerun the slide-making process again.

You could also consider using [RDBmerge](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/addins/rdbmerge.htm) to collect all workbook sheets into one Excel and using formulas to create a kind of staging area which is used for linking with Powerpoint. This would have the benefit that when you iterate a list of worksheet names, your lookup (e.g. using vlookup or index/match) functions would grab the appropriate data into the staging area. SlideFab could then create all slides at once through changing the selected worksheet in a repetitive way.

In case of questions, feel free to reach out.

Disclaimer: I am the owner of SlideFab 2.

Cheers

Jens